# Failed to connect to repository : Failed to create http proxy uri

Tags: git, jenkins

After browsing the similar issues I'm still not able to resolve the connection to bitbucket via the Bitbucket plugn in Jenkins.

The steps I have taken so far.

1. I'm running Jenkins locally (on Windows fyi).
2. I've pointed Jenkins to git.exe (to the bin folder of the local git installation, appended \git.exe)
3. I've created a tunnel using ngrok to acces the local Jenkins instance
4. Set up the webhook in bitbucket
5. Disabled the crsf option of Jenkins (was giving error earlier)

When trying to acccess an open repository (inputting it in the url field of the git option in Jenkins) I get the aforementioned error:
Failed to connect to repository : Failed to create http proxy uri

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below points:-

> 1. Provide SSH repository link git@yourgitserver.com:REPO.git
> 2. Under credentials >> Select Username and Authentication key (go to your server, Generate SSH keys ssh-keygen... Copy keys to
>      JENKINS_HOME/,ssh)

It should help, in case of any error update the question with error log.

Comment: This looks to be the issue. I'm looking into installing the plugin. Have some connectivity issues. Will update you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. Needed to add a ssh plugin to jenkins and generate the keys.